# Synchronous rendering using qt3d causes crashing

Tags: qt, qt3d

qt3d causes my application to unexpectedly crash when using the RenderAspect in synchronous mode. If i use it in threaded mode, my application works fine.

```
renderAspect = new Qt3DRender::QRenderAspect(Qt3DRender::QRenderAspect::Synchronous);
```

Is this a bug? Or am I missing a step somewhere?

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-47392

Comment: i get this error when i try the solution proposed on that page `ASSERT: "allocator->isEmpty()" in file backend\renderer.cpp, line 564`

Comment: It is not an error, it is an assert

Comment: the application still crashes